# Conclusion about Convergence of Series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assume that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n < \infty$$ and $a_n\geq0$.

What can be said about the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$ then? For example, I would have liked to say $$a_n<\frac{1}{n}$$for all $n\geq N_0$ for some $N_0$, but that is false, since we can always find a sequence whose series diverges slowlier than $\frac{1}{n}$.

In that case, what kind of statement *can* be made about the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$, apart from $a_n\to0$?

For example, if we know can factor $$ a_n = b_n c_n $$ and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n = \infty$, what can we say about $b_n$ in terms of $c_n$? Something like $b_n$ is necessarily smaller than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from $a_n\rightarrow 0$, we do not have much information. It is a common misbelief that $\sum a_n < \infty$ implying $na_n \rightarrow 0$.

In fact, $\sum a_n < \infty$ and $na_n\rightarrow 0$ do not imply each other.

See this example:

$$
a_n = \begin{cases} \frac1n &\mbox{ if } n=2^k \mbox{ for some integer } k\geq 0 \\
0 &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Also this example:

$$
a_n = \frac1{n \ln(n+1)}.$$

About the other question about $a_n=b_nc_n$ where $\sum c_n =\infty$, we set up similarly as in the first example:

$$
b_n = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{ if } n=2^k \mbox{ for some integer } k\geq 0 \\
0 &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases},$$

$$
c_n = \frac1n.
$$

Then $\sum a_n < \infty$ and $\sum c_n = \infty$. Also $b_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Thus, we cannot say that $b_n<1$ for $n\geq N_0$.

Comment: I think the question was "if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n<+\infty $, then there is $N_0$ s.t. $a_n\leq \frac{1}{n}$ when $n\geq N_0$, and your both example respect this condition (and in fact it's correct). But since someone downvoted my answer, I probably didn't understand well the question...

Comment: My first example shows that OP's question "If $\sum a_n < \infty$ then there is $N_0$ s. t. $a_n < \frac 1n$ when $n\geq N_0$" is false. The example also shows that the claim in your answer is false.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you perhaps comment on the second part of the question, involving $a_n = b_n c_n$?

Comment: Sure, I will update my  answer soon.

Comment: @i707107, would it however be correct to say the following: If $\sum a_n = C < \infty$ converges, $a_n = b_n c_n $, and $c_n > 0$, then $ b_n c_n \leq \sum_m b_m c_m < C$ so that $b_n < C (c_n)^{-1}$?

Comment: If $c_n\neq 0$, yes.